# AlarmManager doesn't work on samsung device with Android lollipop 5.0.2

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile

I have an issue with the AlarmManager API, it doesn't fire at all on my samsung device, but it works on other Android device...

My code is like that:

```
 public void setAlarm(int hourAlarm,  int minutesAlarm, int numeroAlarm, boolean yesOrNoRepeatAlarm) {


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, numeroAlarm, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Log.i("numeroAlarm", numeroAlarm + "");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    if( (calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > hourAlarm) ||
            ( calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == hourAlarm && calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) > minutesAlarm)) {

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourAlarm);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesAlarm);

    Log.i("timeInMillis", calendar.getTimeInMillis() + "");
    Log.i("repeatingAlarm", yesOrNoRepeatAlarm + "");

    if(yesOrNoRepeatAlarm) {

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
    else {

        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

It works perfectly on other device (specially on kitkat) but not on lolipop in my samsung device,
do you have any idea please ?

Comment: If I had to guess, you are being bitten by a Samsung proprietary battery extension technology, akin to what in Android 6.0 is Doze mode. Search through your device's battery/power settings and see if you can find if this is enabled. If it is, disable it (or whitelist your app, if that is an option) and re-run your test. If your code now works, you know the source of your difficulty. There are similar features for SONY devices and probably others, in addition to Android 6.0+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and after a lot of searching and workaround, I figured that Smart Manager of Samsung Devices in `Lollipop` and above may be the problem. This component can delay the Alarm Manager to goes off, it is triggered after 3 minutes, if the mobile is working on battery and with the screen closed. Of course you can deactivate the Smart Manager look at [this](http://onlinesupport.miradore.com/hc/en-us/articles/207687835-2016-02-17-Samsung-Smart-Manager-blocks-Android-device-management) :

- Launch Samsung Smart Manager application on the device
- Tap Battery
- Tap App optimization
- Detail
- Find Your APP
- Select "Disabled for"

But in my case it didn't work, neither disabling the Smart Manager worked in 2 Samsung devices with `Lollipop` . What it did work was to "fool" Smart Manager by refactoring the name of my application's package to contains the `String` "alert" or "alarm", for example `com.example.alarm.myApplication`. You can also refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074955/android-exact-alarm-is-always-3-minutes-off) for more information.